# Pulling in POM dependency Hierarchies

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, maven, maven-dependency-plugin

I'm attempting to use a ruby on rails application to look through and visually organize dependencies. 
As of now, I'll be using the Maven Dependency tree plugin.

However (if my understanding of this is correct), I cannot run "mvn dependency:tree" in a ruby script on someone else's computer. So the pom files/project must be local.

The only idea I've come up is to pull the entire Github repository into the rails app, which I haven't been able to find a way to do this (Problem 1). Secondly, that would take a long time, but that doesn't matter for my purposes.

Are there better ways to do this that I'm just missing in my research?

Comment: I think what mvn help:effective-pom does is more suited to what you plan to do?

Comment: Unfortunately not, I need to use the -Dincludes tag in maven to specify certain versions. Additionally, the output isn't what I'm looking for. 

I mostly need a way to pull dependencies in through a rails application using a git url or something.

Comment: The maven-dependency-plugin has the goal `tree` with supplemental paraemters like `-DoutputType=dot` which can be used to create graphs via `graphviz` which produces really nice things.

Comment: What do you mean by pulling dependencies in rails app? Why not using [`mvn dependency:copy-dependencies`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/copy-dependencies-mojo.html] which can be used to get all dependencies your project has?

Comment: Problem with -outputtype is that it a) if you specify a folder, It prints out one graph, and that's the last dependency in the project. I've tried appendOutput but it appends literally, which breaks the graph code, as well as creating duplicates. Let me take a second to look at copy-dependencies

Comment: @khmarbaise, I don't think that suits my need. Specifically, I need to be able to take a project's poms, on all levels. Which I can get with dependency:tree as is. I use append output so that all the poms from the project get appended as one. Except it's a literal append as opposed to one that adheres to the hierarchy. However I want to do this in a Rails App. So the maven plugin and git need to be local to the rails app (if my understanding is correct)

Comment: Than please explain more in detail what you like to achieve.

Comment: Specifically, I want to create a rails app that will take in a java git repository url in the config, and be able to organize the dependencies from the poms in the project.